# How to get the edge object data of a vertex in orient db using python

Tags: python, orientdb

```
import pyorient

# create connection 
client = pyorient.OrientDB("localhost", 2424) 

# open databse 
client.db_open( "Test", "admin", "admin" )

requiredObj = client.command(' select from chat where app_cat=appCategory and module=module and type=type and prob_cat=problemCategory  ')

print requiredObj[0]
```

Output:

```
#Output
{'@Chat':{'prob_cat': 'PERFORMANCE', 'type': 'NON FUNCTIONAL', 'module': 'app', 'out_': <pyorient.otypes.OrientBinaryObject object at 0x10d1d6c10>, 'app_cat': 'RETAIL', 'issue': 'Non Capture of Data'},'version':7,'rid':'#22:0'}
```

Here I want to rebind the `out_': <pyorient.otypes.OrientBinaryObject object>` using python.  When I try this code to debind the object this error comes

```
print requiredObj[0].out_[0]

TypeError: 'OrientBinaryObject' object does not support indexing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
requiredObj = client.command(' select expand(out()[0]) from chat where app_cat=appCategory and module=module and type=type and prob_cat=problemCategory  ')

print(requiredObj[0])
```

Hope it helps